Rank(A + B) = Rank(A)
Let  $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be two matrices, where:

$A$ is a very low-rank matrix with  $\text{Rank}(A) = r \ll \min(m, n)$,
$B$ is a full-rank matrix with $\text{Rank}(B) = \min(m, n)$,
$\text{Rank}(A + B) = \text{Rank}(A) = r$.

Is it possible to get matrices $A$ and $B$ that verify these conditions and what implications can we get in this situation.

It's not hard to show that $\text{rank}(A+B) \ge \text{rank}(B)-\text{rank}(A)$, and so, you won't be able to find such $A,B$ unless $r \ge \min(m,n)/2$.

This cannot be true for $r$ too small, but a trivial example achieves the bound.
Bounding $r \ge \frac n 2$
The subadditivity of rank puts bounds on the value of $r$. We have
$$B = (A+B) + (-A)$$
and thus
$$\operatorname{Rank}(B) \le \operatorname{Rank}(A+B) + \operatorname{Rank}(-A).$$
Using $\operatorname{Rank}(-A) = \operatorname{Rank}(A)$ plus your conditions, we have
$$\min\{n, m\} \le r + r = 2r.$$
Achieving the bound
Choose square block matrices with $\frac n 2 \times \frac n 2$ blocks as follows:
$$A := \left[\begin{matrix}-I & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right],$$
$$B := \left[\begin{matrix}I & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{matrix}\right].$$
This gives
$$A + B = \left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{matrix}\right].$$
Observe that $\operatorname{Rank}(A) = \operatorname{Rank}(A+B) = \frac n 2$ while $\operatorname{Rank}(B) = n$.
